# What's the best way to detect crowds?

Tags: k-means, distance, clustering

I have a dictionary containing people and the distance between each pair in the following format:

```
{
    "ID_person1": {"ID_person2": 100, "ID_person3": 50},
    "ID_person2": {"ID_person1": 100, "ID_person3": 40},
    "ID_person3": {"ID_person1": 50, "ID_person2": 40},
}
```

Since I have all distances between pairs, I'm using `K-means` to divide them into `k` clusters (groups), given `k`, where all elements in a group are as close as possible to the other elements in the same group.

Since `K-means` is iterative, is there any ohter way to detect crowds with better performance.

Comment: can you share a sample (reproducible) of the structure of your data?

Comment: without more context, I would go with a density-based algorithm such as DBSCAN, since I assume you do not have a prior knowledge of the number of clusters

Comment: I also assume you should create an X matrix with features for each personid for example mean distance of its k closest neighbours, closest id, remotest id, etc and whit that matrix you can now apply a cluster algorithm

Comment: Let me edit the structure of my data. The number of clusters should be relation between the number of people and the number of elements in a group. I think it's not part of the algorithm discussed here because it's quite easy.